# how do I insert values and getting results from multiple sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So for some context I play a game called EvE Online, currently I'm building a spreadsheet to actually calculate some manufacturing that is involved. I'm not sure if this will be clear of what I want to achieve but I'll give it a shot.

What I'm trying to accomplish is, I have multiple sheets that contain how many minerals is needed to build ships, with a Grand Total at the bottom along with the total of each minerals that is needed. For example:

```
    B           | C         | D       | E        | F       | G       | I    
    Ship 1      | Tritanium | Pyerite | Mexallon | Isogen  | Nocxium | Zydrine
    Grand Total | 1,999,999 | 750,000 | 345,999  | 200,000 | 31,191  | 16,000
```

I have multiple different sheets with each one being a different ship. What I'm trying to figure out is, lets say on a blank sheet I have the following:

```
    Tritanium
    Pyerite
    Mexallon
    Isogen
    Nocxium
    Zydrine
```

Is there a way for me to enter in Values into Column B (Trit/Pye/Mexa all in Column A) and in Column D have it automatically list out the certain ships that I have enough material for? I was thinking of some kind of code that has to involve,

```
IF Tritanium > INDIRECT THEN list ships
```

But I'm at a lost of how exactly do I get this to work. I can see it in my head but can't implement it on paper. Again if there needs to be any clarification please let me know and I'll try my best to clarify it!

Thank you again in advance!

Comment: Is there a reason you need separate sheets for every ship type? This would be easier if you could have a single table listing ship type and matching minerals requirements

Comment: The reason why it's multiple sheets is because if it was on one sheet, the sheet would be about 1000+ lines of context getting to the grand total. I like having it on multiple sheets just to be more organized as well.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad But lets say everything is on the same sheet with all the grand totals and the name of the ships next to the grand total, how would that look for formula wise if I wanted to plug in numbers for Trit/Pye/etc would it be something like, `=IF(AND(Trit>C12,Pye>D12...),'highlight', 'no highlight'` Or... would it be completely different?

Comment: @maykid I too highly suggest putting all the data in one sheet; there are countless advantages to this. For example, you can format as a table, filter down to certain ships using name or various resource requirements. You could also put conditional formatting on the table which I think you would like.

Comment: Also, if you add a column with the ship type, you can filter by those, e.g. list all transport ships.